# Select an Object to Pick Up on Mouse Over

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to Unity, but I have 1.5 years of experience in Java. I understand most of the unityscript stuff, but I am still trying to figure out how to pick up an object from the scene in first person. Here is what I have for picking things up, but I have no idea how to tell the computer which object to pick up, thanks!

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {

}

var SpawnTo : Transform; 
var Object1 : Transform; 
var dist = 4;
private var isHolding = false;
function Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Object1.position) < dist){
            isHolding = !isHolding;
        }
    }
if(isHolding == true){
    Object1.rigidbody.useGravity = false; 
    Object1.parent = SpawnTo;
    Object1.transform.position = SpawnTo.transform.position;
    Object1.transform.rotation = SpawnTo.transform.rotation;
}else{
    SpawnTo.transform.DetachChildren();
    Object1.rigidbody.useGravity = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made a prefab which does just that - unfortunately I always browse SO from a computer where I don't have my unity projects but I'll post it as soon as I'm in front of my own computer!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using RaycastHit and Physics while setting a minimal distance from the object so it can be picked.

[RaycastHit - JS - Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)